# Problems with running of idempiere project

Tags: idempiere

I am trying to run idempiere client project and i have he following error when i try to run adempiere-client.sh:
adempiere-client.sh: 20: /usr/lib/jvm/openlogic-openjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/bin/java/bin/java: not found
How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused because the script adempiere-client.sh is from the adempiere project and in iDempiere is named idempiere-client.sh

If you plan to use iDempiere, I recommend you to avoid using the swing client, it still works but is pretty obsolete and unmaintained, we stopped maintenance long time ago basically because this swing client has security issues that cannot be solved.

All the big new stuff is on the more robust zk web client.

Comment: In this case the script adempiere-client.sh is exactly from the idempiere project.